# Incomplete file download when waiting minutes before clicking open/save in dialog

Tags: xml, jsf, jaxb, download

I am working on a JSF based web application that provides open/save dialog for the user to download an XML file. If user clicks open/save immediately once open/save dialog appears, the file is downloaded completely. But if there is a delay of more than 90 seconds to click open/save after the dialog appears, the downloaded contents are incomplete.

Below is my code snippet.

```
Student student  = getStudentData();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Student.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/xml");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"studentData.xml\"");
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(student, response.getWriter());
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

UPDATE 1:
I tried the temp file approach suggested as the data is large. The temp file is created with proper contents. But the original problem still persists. Below is my code snippet. Am I missing anything?

```
student  = getStudentData();
File tmpFile = new File("C:\\studentDataTmp.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Student.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(student, tmpFile);

FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/xml");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"studentData.xml\"");
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(tmpFile);
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
ByteStreams.copy(input, output); //ByteStreams from Google guava

facesContext.responseComplete();
//Close the streams
```

Comment: Isn't the session just expired in the meanwhile?

Comment: No. The session doesn't get expired. Either the file is partially downloaded or open/save dialog just getting closed without downloading/error.

Comment: Okay. As to the code, I'm only nowhere seeing a `facesContext.responseComplete()`, but that wouldn't explain why it apparently works when the download is immediately started. So perhaps you already had it in the code, but it slipped the copypaste. As to the concrete problem, to my best guess, JAXB marshaller perhaps does not like being opened that long. Try marshalling immediately to a temp file (or very maybe a `byte[]` in memory if they aren't that big) and then stream that instead.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the inputs. The issue seems to be with the server configuration. After changing com.sun.grizzly.writeTimeout option of Glassfish, the waiting time can be increased and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed after adding JVM option -Dcom.sun.grizzly.writeTimeout=300000. Refer [Impact of grizzly.writeTimeout in file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172408/impact-of-grizzly-writetimeout-in-file-download) for more details.