# Impact of grizzly.writeTimeout in file download

Tags: download, glassfish-3, grizzly

I am working on a JSF based web application that provides open/save dialog for the user to download an XML file. If user clicks open/save immediately once open/save dialog appears, the file is downloaded completely. But if there is a delay of more than 90sec, the file is either not downloaded or the downloaded contents are incomplete. ([Incomplete file download when waiting minutes before clicking open/save in dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089080/incomplete-file-download-when-waiting-minutes-before-clicking-open-save-in-dialog))

I am using Glassfish V3 server. After going through the Glassfish survival guide in java.dzone, I modified com.sun.grizzly.writeTimeout to 300000. As per my understanding from various blogs, this jvm option corresponds to the time before Grizzly stop waiting for the browser to read the response bytes. By default, if the browser haven’t read all the response bytes after 30 seconds, Grizzly drops the connection. As I have changed to 300000ms, I thought Grizzly will drop the connection after 300seconds. However, now the contents are properly downloaded if the waiting time to click open/save is < 15 minutes. If waiting time is more than 15 minutes, the contents are incomplete.
I would like to know the behavior and impact of com.sun.grizzly.writeTimeout on file download.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grizzly makes **3** attempts to send at least 1 byte of data. Each attempt may take {com.sun.grizzly.writeTimeout} milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks Alexey for the clarification.

Comment: Is there any maximum limit for writeTimeout? I've changed the value to 600000ms. But the connection is closed after 16 minutes.

Comment: The maximum value is Integer.MAX_VALUE. There is one more value, that can impact the servlet processing logic - "request timeout", it's time given to a servlet to complete processing of a single request. You can set/change it using asadmin command like: "asadmin set
server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.request-timeout-seconds=<SECONDS || -1>"